# Selenium Scroll Down Facebook Album Several Times

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, scroll

I try to scraping Facebook album but there is two scroll bar in the page and I want to know how to locating the inside scroll bar so it can automatically scroll down

[image: I want to scroll the blue one]

I try to use

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

but it doesn't work. I also tried

```
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"body").send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

but I must click the scroll bar manually first to make it scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command worked for me:

```py
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", 600)
```

The entire code I used is:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
)

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.facebook.com/"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='email']"))).send_keys(my_email)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='pass']"))).send_keys(my_password)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='login']"))).click()

time.sleep(1)
url = "album address"
driver.get(url)
for i in range(10):
    image = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@aria-label='Photo album photo'])[last()]")))
    image.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but it still didn't work for me. I add the album example I tried to scrape, maybe you can help me with another solution. Thanks again

Comment: I will try, but not now since currently I'm busy on my work.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I really appreciate it

Comment: I have updated the answer. It not scrolls to the end, but do scrolls several times. You can add the stop condition there by yourself.